# Inheritance, background thread and RAII

Tags: c++, c++11, raii, stdthread

I have a base class that can start background thread, and stop it when needed. That thread calls two virtual methods `Open()` and `Close()`. So all inherited classes can re-implement this methods, but not starting/stoping thread routine (it more difficult than in example). I want to follow RAII principle and start/stop thid thread in constructor/destructor of base class.

The problem is, that calling virtual methods in constructor/destructor is a bad practice and didn't work in my case.
  Here is a shot example of my problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

class Base {
public:
  Base() {
    bg_thread_ = std::thread([this] {
      Open();
      while(!is_stop_) {
      // do stuff
      }
      Close();
    });
  }
  ~Base() {
    is_stop_ = true;
    if(bg_thread_.joinable()) {
      bg_thread_.join();
    }
  }
private:
  virtual void Open() {
    std::cout << "Base open" << std::endl;
  }
  virtual void Close() {
    std::cout << "Base close" << std::endl;
  }
  std::thread bg_thread_;
  std::atomic<bool> is_stop_{false};
};

class Inherited : public Base {
  virtual void Open() override {
    std::cout << "Inherited open" << std::endl;
 }
  virtual void Close() override {
    std::cout << "Inherited close" << std::endl;
 }
};

int main() {
  Inherited inherited;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Inherited open
Base close
```

And without sleep is:

```
Base open
Base close
```

My current approach is to call `Start()` method after constructor and `Stop()` before destructor, but I want solution with RAII.

```
void Start() {
  bg_thread_ = std::thread([this] {
    Open();
    while(!is_stop_) {
    // do stuff
    }
    Close();
  });
}

void Stop() {
  is_stop_ = true;
  if(bg_thread_.joinable()) {
    bg_thread_.join();
  }
}
```

Comment: You can call `Stop()` inside the destructor and you should be safe.

Comment: If I call `Start()` in constructor and `Stop()` in destructor the output will be:
Inherited open
Base close

Comment: Actually Base class `Close` and `Open` are pure virtual. And if I call `Stop()` in Base class destructor the program will crash with `Pure virtual method called` error

Comment: I meant call `Start` after you create the object. But leave `Stop` in the destructor, so you do not have to call it manually (to achieve RAII).

Comment: If I leave `Stop()` in Base class destructor the program will crash. Or I need to call `Stop()` in every inherited from base class destructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is independent of threads. If you call virtual methods in the constructor of the `Base`, the `Inherited` object is not yet created so the `Base` implementations of the methods are called (or you get an error if they are pure virtual). If you call virtual methods in the destructor of `Base` the `Inherited` object is already destroyed so again the `Base` version of the virtual methods are called again.

Calling the methods from another thread does not change this behaviour. But the starting of the thread might take longer than the construction of the `Inherited` object so the object is fully constructed and the `Inherited` methods are called at the beginning of the worker thread.

One solution is to move the RAII to another object. So you don't call `Start` and `Stop` in `Base`s constructor and destructor. Then you can build a `StartStopThing` which takes a `Base` (by reference or by pointer) and calls `Start` and `Stop` in its constructor and destructor. Or you build a `StartStopThing` template class which takes `Inherited` as template argument, builds an `Inherited` object and calls the `Start` and `Stop` methods.